# Can I Use Python in Ionic for Backend work

Tags: python, ionic-framework, backend, hybrid-mobile-app

Can I use Python as a backend for my ionic app? i am new to ionic as well as backend development. If not python suggest some good language for backend development. I am working on a hybrid app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly work with Python. There is an awesome framework called Django which will easen up your development.

However, if you are new to backend development and are already developing the ionic app I strongly recomend using NodeJS.
It is Javascript running on the server machine. The reason is that you will be developing on the same languages on both sides, simplifying thelearning curve. NODEJS is a magnificent language that works a little different than others since it runs on the same process using an event loop to handle incoming requests. It is worth taking a look, you will be making serious functionality in very little time. Take a look at Sequelize to work with SQL databases in an abstracted ORM way (I dont know if you are familiar with databases but it brings clases and objects to talk to DB,  so you for get about sql commands like select, join...).

In NodeJS there are a lot of modules that you can just import like libraries in Java or C and call complex functionality through simple javascript code.

Take a loop at Express framework for Node to make the server as a rest api.

Your question was a little broad so I dont know what else you would like to know, if you have any further question I can certainly help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, That is a lot of info in one shot. i will go through NodeJS, is it similar to AngularJs?

Comment: @Gabriel how would the app be deployed in case I used python? should I deploy ionic app (frontend) and the python app (server) independently or will they be uploaded together as one app. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use python using django rest framework as a backend for your ionic app....